# MLA quoting part of a sentence as a sentence

Tags: quotes, mla

Let's say there is a sentence that I want to quote.

eg. While John read a book, he fell off a cliff, and ate an apple.

If I want to quote "he fell off a cliff, and ate an apple" as a sentence it self, how would I do that.

Some sentence here. "...He fell off a cliff, and ate an apple." Another sentence.

OR

Some sentence here. "He fell off a cliff, and ate an apple." Another sentence.

Which is correct, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MLA doesn't let you change capitalization silently. If the part of the quote you're using is lowercase, then you should use brackets and no ellipsis:

> [H]e fell off a cliff, and ate an apple

If the part of the quote started with a capital letter, you wouldn't need to change it to be uppercase so you would indicate it's not the start of the sentence with an ellipsis (for the sake of example, pretend this isn't comma splice):

> ... John read a book, he fell off a cliff, and ate an apple

See the [MLA Style Center](https://style.mla.org/ellipsis-beginning-quotation/) for more details.